# Strange behavior when displaying checkboxes on inline VF

Tags: visualforce-component, inline-visualforce

The following issue is on the Pro Edition and does not happen on Enterprise. I have this custom grid with several checkboxes in it. This grid is rendered through an inline VF component/section on the Accounts page layout.

Now, I can't get to display the checkbox inline unless the same checkbox is displayed in the detail section. Whatever checkboxes I have left out from detail, **is not** displayed inline. Here is a snapshot of my Account page, which shows the same 3 details checkboxes (at the top)  displayed inline in the single-row grid...nothing more, nothing less:

[image]

How can I get to display inline without displaying the same field in detail? Right now, it pretty much defeats the very purpose of having the VF section.

Appreciate your help; here is the VF page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
 <apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock" mode="inlineEdit">
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!quickSave}" id="saveButton" value="Save"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<!-- first row -->
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account}" var="c"> 

        <apex:column headerValue="Fund/Status" width="111">
            <apex:outputText >
                <b>EJF</b>
            </apex:outputText>


        </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="On Approved List" width="111">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_Approved__c}">
               <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                       showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                       changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                       resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
            </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Pending Approval" width="111">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_Pending__c}"> 
              <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
            </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Denied Approval" width="111">
           <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_Denied__c}"> 
              <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
            </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Removed From Approved" width="127">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_Removed__c}"> 
              <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
            </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="ADV Part II Sent" width="123">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_ADV__c}"> 
                <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
            </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Fee Disclosure Signed" width="111">
           <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_FeeDisc__c}"> 
              <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
           </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Invested" width="101">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_Invested__c}"> 
                 <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
            </apex:outputfield>


        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Redeemed" width="101">
            <apex:outputField value="{!c.EJF_Redeemed__c}"> 
              <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick"
                                      showOnEdit="saveButton"
                                      changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" 
                                      resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/> 
            </apex:outputfield>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
<!-- end of first row -->
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professional Edition cannot do this without adding an "a la carte" option. You would have to buy "custom profiles and page layouts" in order to fix the problem. The reason behind this is because without multiple page layouts, which includes "field level security," the page layout controls the field's visibility (e.g. removing the field from the layout removes its visibility attribute, and adding it restores the visibility); this directly adds/removes fields from reports, etc. When you have multiple layouts, you can specify if the field is visible irrespective of its position on any layout.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What you say does make sense. One question though: In EE, I did not create any profiles or set any fields to visible. I have just one page layout, the standard one and used that. So would you say that by default, the fields were set to visible and thats why I can use them inline?

Comment: One of the steps when creating a field in EE asks for the default visibility. If you check the boxes, they'll appear inline without being on the page, if not, they won't. Most people click through those settings without realizing they're granting access by default. It'd be worth paying attention to next time you create a custom field.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all the fields to the standard page layout and then [override the standard buttons](http://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/links_customize_override.htm) such as Edit, View to a full on custom VF page. That is a lot of work to maintain and I would only do it if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Wow, that seems like a lot of work. Thanks for the link too. Let me try to understand what you said. You're saying I have a full on custom VF page instead of the standard one? Where would my custom grid show then?

Comment: Yes, it is a ton of work. The custom grid would just be part of the custom VF page rather than an embedded page. Here's an example showing how to [create a page that has tabs for the related lists](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm).